# The requested <URL path>'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].' was not found on this server for edit and delete links

Tags: php, gridview, crud

I've a page, index.php, which does CRUD operations and displays data from MySQL with pagination. Everything's working fine except the "Edit" and "Delete" links in the grid table.

Here's the code

```
<?php

   $connection=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db('test1',$connection) or die(mysql_error());

   //displaying 5 results per page
   $per_page = 5;
   //number of adjacent links to show left and right of the current page.
   $adjacents = 5; 

  //execute a mysql query to retrieve count of total users in table
  $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM users") or die(mysql_error());

  //get total number of pages to be shown from  total result
  $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

  //get current page from URL ,if not present set it to 1
  $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1 ;

  //calculate actual start page with respect to Mysql 
  $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

  //execute a mysql query to retrieve  all result from current page by using LIMIT keyword in mysql
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users order by id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page") or die(mysql_error());

  // @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Pagination starts here @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

  //store pagination result in a string so that we can place any where in page.
  $pagination="";

  //if current page is first show first only else reduce 1 by current page
  $Prev_Page = ($page==1)?1:$page - 1;

  //if current page is last show last  only else add  1 to  current page
  $Next_Page = ($page>=$pages)?$page:$page + 1;



  //if we are not on first page show first link
  if($page!=1) $pagination.= '<a href="?page=1">First</a>';

  //if we are not on first page show previous link
  if($page!=1) $pagination.='<a href="?page='.$Prev_Page.'"><code><<</code>Previous</a>';

  //we are going to display 5 links on pagination bar
  $numberoflinks=5;

  //find the number of links to show on right of current page
  $upage=ceil(($page)/$numberoflinks)*$numberoflinks;

  //find the number of links to show on left of current page
  $lpage=floor(($page)/$numberoflinks)*$numberoflinks;

  //if  number of links on left of current page are zero we start from 1
  $lpage=($lpage==0)?1:$lpage;

  //find the number of links to show on right of current page and make sure it must be less than total number of pages
  $upage=($lpage==$upage)?$upage+$numberoflinks:$upage;
  if($upage>$pages)$upage=($pages-1);

  //start building links from left to right of current page
  for($x=$lpage; $x<=$upage; $x++){

  //if current building link is current page we don't show link,we show as text else we show as linkn


  $pagination.=($x == $page) ? ' <strong>'.$x.'</strong>' : ' <a href="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a>' ;
  }

  //we show next link and last link if user doesn't on last page
  if($page!=$pages) $pagination.=  '  <a href="?page='.$Next_Page.'">Next>></a>';
  if($page!=$pages) $pagination.=  ' <a href="?page='.$pages.'">Last</a>';

  //display final pagination bar.
  ?>

  <!-- @@@@@@@@@@@@ Grid to show the results fetched from database @@@@@@@@@-->

  <table width="70%" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">Id</td>
      <td align="center">First Name</td>
      <td align="center">Last Name</td>
      <td align="center">Created</td>


<td align="center">Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>

  <?php 
  //while we going through each row we display info
  while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
  ?>
  <tr>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row->id;  //row id ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row->fname; // row first name ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row->lname; //row las tname  ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row->created; //row created time ?></td>


<td id="action"> 

<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=Edit&amp;pid='.$id.'">

Edit</a> | 

<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=Delete&amp;pid='.$id.'" 




onclick="return confirmToDelete('.$id.');" >Delete</a><br /></td>





    </tr>      
 <?php       


}
 ?>

 </table>
 <div class="pagination" style="text-align:center"><?php  echo $pagination; ?></div>
```

"edit" and "delete"  is in separate files, but these files are included in index.php page 
When edit and delete are run separately they work fine, but when i include then in index.php
the links "Edit" and "Delete" show

"The requested '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].' was not found on this server" error

What am I doing wrong? Kindly help!

Thanks
Naz

Answer (score 0):

Replace these links :

```
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?action=Edit&amp;pid=<?=$id?>">

<a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?action=Delete&amp;pid=<?=$id?>">
```

Comment: does not work. even though i set full permission to the folder, it says "you dont have permission to acces the folder"

Comment: replace `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` by `./` if the name of your script is index.php